# React Native | Can't find variable in Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react-native app I've got 3 files I want to connect together

File 1 `Data` Where I've currently got my test data stored

File 2 `Products` Where the products items get styling and layout is build

File 3 `ProductListScreen` Where the list of products get displayed

When I importing the `Data` & `Products` file into my `ProductListScreen` seems to work fine, but for unknown reasons I get an `ReferenceError` stating `Can't find variable products`

This error happens on line 73 of the `ProductListScreen` in my app which is:

```
<Products products={books} onPress={this.props.addItemToCart} />
```

Now I can't figure out why it can't find `products` since it's declared at

line 16 of my `ProductListcreen` file :

```
import Products from '../../components/Products';
```

Did I not import it correctly? Or is there something else at fault?

*I've only started programming with react-native several weeks ago, so excuse me for my lack of knowledge on the subject*

---

Currently my file structure is set up like this

- App.js
- Data.js
- Screens folder

  - Product folder

    - ProductListScreen.js
- components folder

  - Product.js

---

**Data file**

```
export const books = [
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'How to Kill a Mocking Bird',
        price: 10
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'War of Art',
        price: 7
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Relentless',
        price: 5.99
    }
]
```

---

**Products file**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Button
} from "react-native";

class Products extends Component {

    renderProducts = (products) => {
        console.log(products)
        return products.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <View key={index} style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                    <Button onPress={() => this.props.onPress(item)} title={item.name + " - " + item.price} />
                </View>
            )
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.renderProducts(this.props.products)}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default Products;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

---

**ProductListScreen file**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import Products from '../../components/Products'
import { books } from '../../Data'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class ProductListScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: 'Electronics'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Products products={books} onPress={this.props.addItemToCart} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addItemToCart: (product) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: product })
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductListScreen);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

Comment: folder name is components or component

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq it's components, thanks just edited it. Did not solve the problem tho.

Comment: Try de-structuring props. Replace `(product)` with `({product})`

Comment: According to your description of your project directory, seems like you need to navigate 2 levels up instead of 1 to find `components/Products` from `ProductListScreen`: `import Products from '../../components/Products'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to restart expo so it recompile and find the changed folder locations.